# Want to update mysql field value like 00001, 00002, 00003

Tags: mysql

```
| id | dataID |
---------------
| 1  | 00001  |
| 2  | 00007  |
| 3  | 00004  |
| 4  | 00007  |
| 5  | 00005  |
```

I want to  rearrange this like

```
| id | dataID |
---------------
| 1  | 00001  |
| 2  | 00002  |
| 3  | 00003  |
| 4  | 00004  |
| 5  | 00005  |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most simple is to use CONCAT function for this.

```
UPDATE 
 table
SET 
 dataID = CONCAT('0000', id)
```

If you want to keep the dataID the same length you need this query

```
UPDATE 
 table
SET 
 dataID = LPAD(id, 5, '0')
```